# Java - printing value mapped to a key, which is read from file

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, mapping

I would like a code in **java** to read a text file, select a value in first column then prints its corresponding value in the second column as shown in the image below.

I managed to read the file using the code shown here but I'm unable to continue.

```
public class readfile {
    private Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readfile r = new readfile();
        r.openFile();
        r.readFile();
        r.closeFile(); 
    }   

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner (new File("filename.txt")); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("file not found "); 
        }
    }   

    public void readFile() {
        while(s.hasNext()) {
            String a = s.next();
            String b = s.next();
            System.out.printf("%s  %s\n",a, b);    
        }
    }   

    public void closeFile() {
        s.close();
    }   
}
```

[image: I would like to code that selects a value in first column and prints its corresponding value in the second column as show in this image]

Comment: Without specific language you probably can only loop over array and check for valeu in first column and if it's equal write second column

Comment: Thank you @MarekMaszay for your response. I have edited my post to make it more clearer. If you have any suggestions after reviewing this post again, please share with me. I'm relatively new in Java.

Comment: Where is the mapping of the two columns? Are they both in the same file? Do they share a line, and if so - with what delimiter to separate the columns? If they do not share a line, are they always one after the other?

Comment: @Assafs, Thanks. I would like to answer your questions: according to the code above, String 'a' and String 'b' maps to the first and second columns respectively. They are both in the same file, share a line and are separated by 'space'. This means that they are always one after another.

Comment: I expended your code a little bit - I hope it helps you understand how to read key-value from a file, and storing them to use later. If you think it's a good solution, I'd appreciate it if you could accept the answer by clicking on the green tick.

Comment: Thanks@Assafs. Let me check how it works then report back.

Comment: @Assafs, I tried the code you suggested but could not print out although it has no errors. I guess it is because my Keys are double numbers. It might work for only intergers or string values.

Comment: Hi @WycliffeKiprop, I tested using your original set of keys, being double numbers. Perhaps you've read some blank characters in the file? I'd suggest adding a printout of the map as it is made from the file, just to be sure the keys are read without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code as the basis for this (I tried to make the most minimal changes) I suggest you store the read values in a Map - this will allow you to get the corresponding value quickly.

```
public class readfile {
    private Scanner s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readfile r = new readfile();
        r.openFile();

        //tokens in a map that holds the values from the file
        Map<String,String> tokens = r.readFile();
        r.closeFile();

        //this section just demonstrates how you might use the map
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String token = scanner.next();

        //This is a simple user input loop. Enter values of the first 
        //column to get the second column - until you enter 'exit'.
        while (!token.equals("exit")) {
            //If the value from the first column exists in the map
            if (tokens.containsKey(token)) {
                //then print the corresponding value from the second column
                System.out.println(tokens.get(token));
            } 
            token = scanner.next();
        }
        scanner.close(); 
    }   

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            s = new Scanner (new File("filename.txt")); 
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("file not found "); 
        }
    }   

    //Note this change - the method now returns a map
    public Map<String,String> readFile() {
    Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        String a = s.next();
        String b = s.next();
        tokens.put(a,b); //we store the two values in a map to use later
    }
    return tokens; //return the map, to be used.
    }    

    public void closeFile() {
        s.close();
    }   
}
```

I hope this illustrates how you can read any key-value pair from a file and store it for use at a later phase.